# Загрузка данных в бд

Tags: android, sqlite

У меня есть android-приложение, на основной странице RecyclerView, который заполняется из базы данных, по клику на какой-то элемент происходит загрузка новых элементов из бд и RecyclerView обновляется. Все работает, все замечательно.

Но, появилась задача, загружать в бд данные из json файла, все парсится и происходит сотни добавлений в бд. Естественно при этой операции приложение замирает на несколько секунд, т.к. у нас происходит все в одном потоке.
Я только начал заниматься разработкой и не знаю как поступить в этом случае, я так понимаю у меня варианта 2:

1. Показать progressbar пользователю и пусть ждет загрузки (чего не хотелось бы)
2. Сделать загрузку в отдельном потоке в фоновом режиме, но при клике пользователя на какой-то элемент RecyclerView, будет происходить чтение в бд, как я понимаю, так делать нельзя и я получу ошибку т.к. с бд работает уже другой поток.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно делать в таких случаях?

Comment: Если у вас android 9+, то вам не о чем беспокоиться. У вас включен [wal](https://source.android.com/docs/core/perf/compatibility-wal) по дефолту и можете спокойно писать из одного потока и читать из разных потоков. и запись не блокирует чтение.  
Для более старых версий андроида придется что-то делать с оптимизацией вставки (наприемр bulk insert) ну и прогресс тоже не помешает. Как вариант, готовить базу заранее, т.е. чтоб приложение уже было с заполненной базой при старте....

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку, это открыло для меня многое)